# X-Domain XML Feed with Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, cross-domain

Ok, so Prototype would not be my choice but the client site uses it and I have to adapt.

I have an XML feed coming through from site A and my function is:

```
new Ajax.Request('somefeedurl.ashx',
{
    method:'get',
    onSuccess: function(transport){
        console.log("Transport: "+transport)
        myParseXml(transport.responseXML);
    },
    onFailure: function(){
        alert('Something went wrong...')
    }
});
```

I have implemented a crossdomain.xml file to allow access to somefeedurl.com but I am still getting the same Origin: is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any way around this using Prototype?

As a second question. Once I do get around this am I correct in running the function myParseXML() to actually do the processing? Ie is transport.responseXML going to give the XML data from the feed?

regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

No. If the other site that provides the XML feed does not [explicitly allow cross-domain requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you can't retrieve it (directly) using Ajax due to the [sop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - any "workaround" would be a security bug.

Regardless of the library you use to wrap you ajax calls in.

See also the docs for [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest), with which the [onsuccess handler will be invoked](http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options). So to answer your second question: No, `responseXML` is already parsed to a Document.

Comment: I take it by directly entering the feed URL in my browser is not the same as requesting it from another domain. Sorry for n00b question but I am not too familiar with cross domain stuff, much prefer to generate my XML on site but not possible in this case

Comment: Yes. You will need to take the XML from your site - i.e proxy the request with your server.

Comment: So with just using local XML how easy is it to parse with prototype? Been googling quite a bit but can't find anything as easy as jQuery parseXML?

Comment: Pls read the docs I've linked. Why do you think that thing is named ***XML** HttpRequest*?